# How to Store a User ID after Login and access from another page in flutter?

Tags: database, flutter, api, dart, postman

** API RESPONSE

```
{
"data": {
    "CityName": null,
    "DOB": "7/07/2022",
    "DeviceType": "0",
    "Email": "test@gmail.com",
    "MobileNo": "1234567891",
    "ProfileImage": "",
    "UserID": "1",
    "UserName": "xyz",
    "UserType": "3"
},
"message": "Successfully login",
"status": 200 
}
```

// Api Services
````

```
Future<Loginmodel?> login() async {
    if (passwordController.text.isNotEmpty && nameController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      var response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse(
            'XYZ',
          ),
          headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
          body: (jsonEncode({
            'UserName': nameController.text,
            'Password': passwordController.text,
            'DeviceToken': '',
            'DeviceType': ''
          })));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var data = jsonDecode(response.body);

        print(data);

        print(data['data']['UserID'].toString());

        if (data['data']['UserID'] == null) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
              .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Invaild Credentials")));
        } else {
          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Homescreen()));

          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
              .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Succesfully Credentials")));
        }

        // await Storage.write(key: "token", value: output["token"]);
      }
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Black Field Not Allowed")));
    }
    }
```

Comment: You can Store your data and retrieve with sharedpreferences. https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Comment: PLzz share Example

Comment: If you want this User ID after your app gets killed, you can use shared preference.
But if it's not like that then you can store it in a singleton class and access it from there.

Comment: Plzz Give me Example in My API Servies  than I am Clear About it .. I Am New In Flutter

Answer (score 1):

Create a class you can use it as per your need. Here is an dummy example change as per your need.

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
class SessionManager {
  final String auth_token = "auth_token";
   late final SharedPreferences prefs;

//set data into shared preferences like this
  Future<void> setAuthToken(String auth_token) async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString(this.auth_token, auth_token);
  }

//get value from shared preferences
  Future<String?> getAuthToken() async {
    final SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? auth_token;
    auth_token = (pref.getString(this.auth_token) ?? null);
    return auth_token;
  }




  clearAll() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.clear();
  }
}
```

Call SessionManager globally inside your class.

```
 SessionManager prefs = SessionManager();
```

And then set user id as follows when success.

```
 prefs.setAuthToken(data['data']['UserID']);
```

You can get the data as follows anywhere in project:

```
  prefs.getAuthToken();// it returns future
```

For getting value

```
 prefs.getAuthToken().then((value) {
  print(value); //this is your used id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create model from https://ashamp.github.io/jsonToDartModel/

create model of just your data no need to create whole model.
for you simplicity i created for you.

```
class UserModel {
  String? CityName;
  String? DOB;
  String? DeviceType;
  String? Email;
  String? MobileNo;
  String? ProfileImage;
  String? UserID;
  String? UserName;
  String? UserType;

  UserModel({
    this.CityName,
    this.DOB,
    this.DeviceType,
    this.Email,
    this.MobileNo,
    this.ProfileImage,
    this.UserID,
    this.UserName,
    this.UserType,
  });
  UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    CityName = json['CityName']?.toString();
    DOB = json['DOB']?.toString();
    DeviceType = json['DeviceType']?.toString();
    Email = json['Email']?.toString();
    MobileNo = json['MobileNo']?.toString();
    ProfileImage = json['ProfileImage']?.toString();
    UserID = json['UserID']?.toString();
    UserName = json['UserName']?.toString();
    UserType = json['UserType']?.toString();
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['CityName'] = CityName;
    data['DOB'] = DOB;
    data['DeviceType'] = DeviceType;
    data['Email'] = Email;
    data['MobileNo'] = MobileNo;
    data['ProfileImage'] = ProfileImage;
    data['UserID'] = UserID;
    data['UserName'] = UserName;
    data['UserType'] = UserType;
    return data;
  }
}
```

in your main function

```
late final SharedPreferences prefs;

void main() async {
  prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

**replace this in your login api call**

```
if (data['data']['UserID'] == null) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Invaild Credentials")));
} else {
  Navigator.push(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Homescreen()));

  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Succesfully Credentials")));
}
```

**with**

```
    if (data['data']['UserID'] == null) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Invaild Credentials")));
    } else {
      prefs.setString("userData", data['data']);
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Homescreen()));
    
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Succesfully Credentials")));
    }
```

Then in any other page do like below

```
LoginModelDataUser userData = LoginModelDataUser();

userData= UserModel.fromJson(prefs.readString("userData"));
```

**Use it like this in you widget**

```
Text(userData.UserName??"")
```

Comment: Exception has occurred.
_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)  this type of error giving me

Comment: how can I use prefs.setString("userData", data['data']); in My Call Api  Give me some suggestion When I Use In My Api Services?

Comment: check update code

Comment: same error ocuuring

Comment: please share screen shot and code

Comment: late final SharedPreferences prefs; < --  I think in code error

Comment: late keyword giving error .. I thinking

Comment: final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

try this.

Comment: I am Not able to for upload photo ..

Comment: where? i didn't get your question

Comment: Is user details work for you or not?

Comment: same error ocuuring

Comment: share screenshot and error too

Comment: i am not able to upload photo

Comment: this error is not related to this.

Comment: I am not able to share screenshot as some issues ...